# Conflicts on having the same group at the start and at the end

Tags: python, regex, pcre

I have a regex that should catch:

```
[=foo]
[="foo"]
[='foo']
```

The begin and the end have to be the same so I'm gonna to capture the quotes and call it at the end with \1. The question mark it's used to accept also no quotes:

```
\[=(['\"]?)(.+)\1\]
```

Working fine if I try it on one row, but when I try to write anything else and call a closure bracket it's going to match until that bracket. Some examples of the behaviours: https://regex101.com/r/4qYzyS/1

Anyone have a solution? To match the 3 patterns that I want without conflicts? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the dot non greedy, i.e. use `(.+?)`.  Also, you might want to turn off the second capturing group, or maybe just remove it completely.  E.g. the following pattern seems to work:

```
\[=([\"']?).+?\1\]
```

### Demo

Here is a sample Python script:

```
input = "[=\"foo\"]\n[=\"Lorem ipsum\"]\n\n[=foo]Lorem ipsum]";
for match in re.finditer(r"\[=([\"']?).+?\1\]", input):
    print match.group(0)

[="foo"]
[="Lorem ipsum"]
[=foo]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do so using this expression:

```
(\[=)(.+)(\])
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DaBkxV/1)

[image]

If you wish to add boundaries instead of using `(.+)`, you might want to use an expression and add any possible chars that you may have in between `[]`, maybe something [similar to](https://regex101.com/r/OSpSy2/1):

```
(\[=)([A-z\s\x22]+)(\])
```

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how the second expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Code

This code shows how the expression would work in Python:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import re

string = "[=foo]Lorem ipsum] with anything else that you wish"
expression = r'((\[=)([A-z\s\x22]+)(\]))'
match = re.search(expression, string)
if match:
    print("YAAAY! \"" + match.group(1) + "\" is a match  ")
else: 
    print(' Sorry! No matches! Something is not right! Call 911 ')
```

#### Output

```
YAAAY! "[=foo]Lorem ipsum]" is a match
```

#### Performance Test

This JavaScript snippet shows the performance of the expression using a simple 1-million times `for` loop.

```js
repeat = 1000000;
start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 var string = "[=foo]Lorem ipsum] with anything else that you wish";
 var regex = /((\[=)([A-z\s\x22]+)(\]))(.*)/g;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "$1");
}

end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Comment: I liked the presentation @Emma. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the `(.+)` non greedy as `(.+?)`, you'll prevent slurping up the rest of the string:

```
\[=([\"']?)(.+?)\1\]/
              ^
```

Comment: Non-greedy regex will not match OP's third sample the way he wants.

Comment: How so? I'm seeing a full string match.

Comment: Check for this string `[=foo]Lorem ipsum]`

Comment: Seems fine to me, it matches `[=foo]` as the OP specified, no?

Comment: I think OP wants to match whole line, till last `]` which is why he has used `.+` greedy quantifier.

Comment: OP says "I have a regex that should catch: `[=foo]`". I (and Tim) took that as the non-greedy quantifier was accidental. Your version interprets it as "match until last `]` in the line" which doesn't seem suggested by OP's post to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193000/discussion-between-ggorlen-and-pushpesh-kumar-rajwanshi).

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is working fine and the reason why it matches the second line is, you have enabled `DOTALL` mode due to which `.` also matches a newline. Just disable `DOTALL` mode by unchecking `s` mode and you will get results like you expect.

**[Regex Demo after disabling DOTALL mode](https://regex101.com/r/4qYzyS/3)**

[image]

Also, in your third sample, I'm not sure whether you want your regex to be a full match or not, but in case you intend to match only `[=foo]` and not `[=foo]Lorem ipsum]` then you should use `[^[\]]+` instead of `.+` in your regex.

Also, as you seem to be wanting to match your string if it is either surrounded by `"` or `'` or nothing from both sides, then you should also include `"` and `'` within the negated character class, so your regex should not match input like this `[="foo]`. Overall the correct regex you should use is this,

**[Regex that you should be using precisely](https://regex101.com/r/4qYzyS/5)**